# How do I decode bits in order to get the original values?

Tags: c#, parsing, bit-manipulation

Assuming I have the following enum

```
[Flags]
enum Options
{
    Option1 = 1 << 0, 
    Option2 = 1 << 1, 
    Option3 = 1 << 2
}
```

And I were to set a variable as follows

```
var options = 0;
options |= Options.Option1; 
options |= Options.Option3; 

// now options should equal Option1 + Option3
// I then store that single value in the database
myDatabase.Options.Submit(options);
```

How do I then parse "Options" in order to get the original values back?

```
public List<Options> ParseOptions(Options options)
{
    // Not sure how to parse the options.
}
```

Comment: `options & Options.Option3 != 0` <-- option 3 is selected. (i think)

Comment: you are right, just put the statement on right between parentheses for avoid types conflicts. Note: you can do check if int returned is not 0, if 0 is not a value of your enumeration(it's can be causes conflicts) I recommend do: `(option & Options.Option3) == Options.Option3`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [`Enum.HasFlag()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) method to see if a particular flag is set.  Just go through all the individual values testing if it is set.

```
var value = Options.Option1 | Options.Option3;
foreach (Options flag in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Options)))
{
    if (value.HasFlag(flag))
    {
        // do something with the flag
    }
}
```

Note that the `HasFlag()` method was added to .NET 4.  It is however logically equivalent to this:

```
public static bool HasFlag(this Enum value, Enum flag)
{
    return (value & flag) == flag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
public List<Options> ParseOptions(Options options)      
{
    var list = new List<Options>(); 

    foreach(MyEnum val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum)))
    {
        if ((val & options) == val)
            List.Add(val);
    }

    return list;
}
```

(not verified in Visual Studio)

Comment: In C# 4.0 you can use `if (options.HasFlag(val)) { ... }` instead of bitwise &.

Comment: @Jack: Strictly speaking, it's better to do `(val & option) == option`, just in case the enum has been setup with some crazy multi-bit values and there's only a partial overlap between `val` and `option`.